# Easiest way to change the behavior of one method without changing the class?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Bit of background: I'm using [IQToolkit](http://iqtoolkit.codeplex.com/) to write a custom data provider that uses `System.Data.Odbc` instead of `System.Data.SqlClient`.

I've run into an issue with the default Parameterizer class, found [here](http://iqtoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/94877#2219362). The below snippet of code is what I need to change, amounting to just one method.

```
    int iParam = 0;
    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression c)
    {
        if (c.Value != null && !IsNumeric(c.Value.GetType())) {
            NamedValueExpression nv;
            TypeAndValue tv = new TypeAndValue(c.Type, c.Value);
            if (!this.map.TryGetValue(tv, out nv)) { // re-use same name-value if same type & value
                string name = "p" + (iParam++);
                nv = new NamedValueExpression(name, this.language.TypeSystem.GetColumnType(c.Type), c);
                this.map.Add(tv, nv);
            }
            return nv;
        }
        return c;
    }
```

I've thought of several ways I could accomplish this, but I don't really like any of them.

1. I have the source, so I could change the source itself and recompile it. However, this would remove a useful bit of code for other SQL dialects, I don't want to ruin that all just for ODBC's sake.
2. I could write my own `Parameterizer` class and use that instead of the default. If I did this, I'd be duplicating 250 lines of code for the sake of changing three or four.
3. I could try to override the class, changing just the method I need. I tried this, but I ran into some problems with the protection levels in the `Parameterizer` class. I like this the best, but I'm not sure I'm doing it quite correctly, or if I even could with the given class design.

Apologies if the question seems vague, but is there any easy way for me to change the behavior of that method without having to change the base class or without duplicating all its code?

**EDIT**: Issues with #3: Can't access `IsNumeric`(private to `Parameterizer`), can't access `Parameterizer.map`, can't access struct `TypeAndValue`, can't access `Parameterizer.language`.

Comment: What issues did you run into with option #3? This seems like the best option to me as well.

Comment: @Adrian See my edit. All problems with protection levels in `Parameterizer`.

Comment: I may be off - but if this is the 'visitor' as it is - you can implement your own visitor - call the default one for all but `VisitConstant` - and just implement that one.

Comment: @NSGaga You mean extend the `DbExpressionVisitor` class? I thought of that, that's option #2. It would definitely work but I'd basically just end up duplicating all of the code in `Parameterizer` except for three or four lines which isn't ideal...

Comment: visitors, visitor pattern - `In essence, the visitor allows one to add new virtual functions to a family of classes without modifying the classes themselves` - i.e. in most cases that's enough on its own. No, sort of, what I'm saying - w/o posting a full answer (I don't have time right now) - you can 'wrap' - not override the original visitor - you don't need too much code - just call default implementations - how much is it '10 methods' or so (just implement inside the 'default' visitor - and redirect to it. **Fully implement the one you need only.**

Comment: @Mansfield Is there a issue with making the private methods public or convert them to extension methods?

Comment: @Justin I'd like to avoid modifying the original source if possible. Other than that there's no issue....

Comment: @Mansfield I really don't see anyway you can do this without changing the source code in some way, short of duplicating all the code.

Comment: @Justin Yes, that's what it looks like. I've just duplicated the code...only 250 lines, not the end of the world. And as it turned out I needed to change more like 30 lines rather than 3 so it's not so bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up just being easier to rewrite the parameterizer. Not sure that this is widely relevant, but the code I had to change, in case anyone is interested:

The problem with this method was that it was attempting to re-use parameters with duplicate types and values. However, since I'm using ODBC style parameters that aren't named, the query has to have the same number of parameters as the query specifies, even if they're exactly the same.

```
protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression c)
{
    if (c.Value != null && !IsNumeric(c.Value.GetType())) {
        NamedValueExpression nv;
        TypeAndValue tv = new TypeAndValue(c.Type, c.Value, iParam);

        string name = "p" + (iParam++);
        nv = new NamedValueExpression(name, this.language.TypeSystem.GetColumnType(c.Type), c);
        this.map.Add(tv, nv);

        return nv;
    }
    return c;
}
```

I also had to modify the `TypeAndValue` constructor to make the hash values for the parameters unique even if their types and values are the same. I did this by adding the parameter number.

```
public TypeAndValue(Type type, object value, int pCount)
{
    this.type = type;
    this.value = value;
    this.hash = type.GetHashCode() + (value != null ? value.GetHashCode() : 0) + pCount;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

e.g. something like this is what I had in mind (based on our comments).

```
public class MyVisitor : DbExpressionVisitor
{
    // cast it to the visitor interface/base - that way you'd have access to all methods,
    // as Parameterizer has to have them publically exposed anyway, for this to work
    readonly DbExpressionVisitor _defaultVisitor;
    public MyVisitor()
    {
        _defaultVisitor = new Parameterizer();
    }
    public Expression VisitProjection(ProjectionExpression proj)
    {
        return _defaultVisitor.Visit(proj);
    }
    // ...same for all others, just...
    // ... 

    // implement your own for one 'route'
    protected Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression c)
    {
        if (c.Value != null && !IsNumeric(c.Value.GetType())) {
            NamedValueExpression nv;
            TypeAndValue tv = new TypeAndValue(c.Type, c.Value);
            if (!this.map.TryGetValue(tv, out nv)) { // re-use same name-value if same type & value
                string name = "p" + (iParam++);
                nv = new NamedValueExpression(name, this.language.TypeSystem.GetColumnType(c.Type), c);
                this.map.Add(tv, nv);
            }
            return nv;
        }
        return c;
    }
}
```

**Visitors, visitor pattern**...

> "In essence, the visitor allows one to add new virtual functions to a
>   family of classes without modifying the classes themselves"

i.e. that means that in most cases that's enough on its own, w/o needing to resort to inheritance, overriding (it's sort of redundant, a bit simplified). You can use that fact to override certain behavior of the original visitor (as you already have a mechanism in place) - and avoid inheritance, and problems you may have.

> The only possible issue with this could be - that the `Parameterizer`
>   doesn't have a default ctor - which is not likely I think as you
>   probably need to anyway.

Comment: I don't quite understand this - from looking at this it seems I'd have to modify the original source to make `Parameterizer` implement an interface as well - is that correct?

Comment: nope @Mansfield - I'm just giving you a 'pseudo code' here - IVisitor is your `DbExpressionVisitor` - you implement that - which VS does automatically and gives a 10/20 blank methods - you just have to add `return _defaultVisitor.Visit(e);` (or w/o return I don't know) - and just 'implmenet' one and only one you need.

Comment: I made lot of errors in a hurry :) but I think it looks ok now

Comment: that still leaves me with the same problems from option #3, Parameterizer has a private constructor, and I can't access the private methods of the `Parameterizer` class that I need. I suppose I'll never be able to access those though...

Comment: you don't need private methods - you can 'cast' it to that visitor and call through that. Basically, I have no idea of specifics - you gotta work that out on your own - if you can override - you for sure can 're-implement' it like I showed you. It's not the same, not nearly the same. Take a look, think about it.

Comment: Except I do need to use the private methods I mentioned from option #3, or else duplicate them in the new class...

Comment: just duplicate the one private method ? What you're saying is that you can't do 'anything' really - then you're sort of stuck as nothing will work - but what I"m saying - whatever you can use to work either of the 3 - you can use with this approach just lot simpler.

Comment: What I'm trying to avoid is duplicating the methods. If it's going to be impossible that's okay, I'll work with it, but I'd prefer not to if there's a way to accomplish that.

Comment: I you can't access it - you gotta reimplement at least one method ?? I'm off - this should work - again, think about it - and work around it - I cannot do the specifics here. Cheers

Comment: no problem mate - sorry, I'm in a hurry, so may sound a bit 'in a rush' :) cheers